# How do I inspect the name of each combobox on a worksheet fo a particular name using VBA-Excell?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have several comboboxes on a worksheet whose object names contain the word Product.  I would like to select each of these comboboxes in order to update the list items.

I have managed to identify comboboxes but I can't seem to identify the name specifically.

```vb
dim CBO as oleboject
set ws = sheets(1)
with sheets(1)
for each cbo in ws.oleobjects
if typename(cbo.object) = "ComboBox" then
 THE CHECK HERE FAILS
end if
next cbo
end with
```

I can't get the code to identify the name of the object.

Comment: Does the check `If Typename(cbo.Object) = "ComboBox"` fail? Or something that comes afterwards? And if it fails, what kind of error do you get?

Comment: Hi Alex, I have a type in my script is defined as an OLEObject and does not fail.  I can read the CBO.Name property but I can't select the specific ComboBox that I would like in order to add items to them.  E.G.  If CBO.Name like "*ToP*" then (finds the correct comboboxes.) I can't seem to get the next steps to work.  With The CBO that I just identified list=array(Item1, Item2, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

So I think you need to do a prior check to ensure that the typename property exists:

```
Sub ComboLoop()
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim OleObj As OLEObject

For Each Ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   For Each OleObj In Ws.OLEObjects
      If OleObj.OLEType = xlOLEControl Then
         If TypeName(OleObj.Object) = "ComboBox" Then
             With OleObj.Object

             'SOME ACTIONS 
             End With
         End If
      End If
   Next OleObj
Next Ws
End Sub
```

I've used this code in the past and it worked for me so hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Earl_of_Duke but I think I made a mistake in what I was trying to ask.  I wanted to identify comboboxes on a spreadsheet that contained a particular string in their name and then add items to those combo boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Instead of using

`CBO.List = array(item1,item2)`,

you need to use

`CBO.Object.List = array(item1,item2)`