# How to generate and populate Listboxes in VBA dynamically?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, populate

I am trying to generate Listboxes (currently in a UserForm) dynamically (depending on the used columns of the source sheet) and populate them with the entries of those belonging columns.

For example:

- Column A has the following entries (one per row): Apple, Banana, Peach
- Column B has: Blue, Green, Red

The UserForm shall generate two ListBoxes (one for Column A, one for Column B) and populate them with the according entries of those columns.

I tried looping through Listboxes but I keep getting errors since I can't figure out how to get the syntax properly. The variable `Lastrow` gives me the number of non-empty cells in a column and functions correctly (code not shown for a better view on the relevant code.

I did the generation of Listbox this way:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 21
    Set LstBx = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.Listbox.1", Name:="Listbox" & i)
Next i
```

Populating the Listboxes seems to be harder for me:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim LB As String
Dim cell As Range

For i = 1 To 21
For Each cell In SourceSheet.Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(LastRow, i)).Cells
    LB = "Listbox" + i
    LB.AddItem cell.Value
Next cell
```

The following combines the generation and population and is the actual code I am trying to fix:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim LB As String
Dim cell As Range

For i = 1 To 21

'Generate
Set LstBx = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.Listbox.1", Name:="Listbox" & i)

'Populate
For Each cell In SourceSheet.Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(LastRow, i)).Cells
    LB = "Listbox" + i

    'the following is the crucial part I am losing hope on:
    'It seems that it is not possible to address Listboxes this way but i cant find another way:
    LB.AddItem cell.Value

Next cell
```

I am expecting a generation and population of the ListBoxes according to the dynamic amount of columns. But I am struggling especially with the adding items to the correct ListBox while looping. In the end, my goal is just to transfer all columns and respective entries into listboxes regarding a dynamic column and row range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference the Listbox by name like this:

`Me.Controls("Listbox" & i).addItem cell.value`

Me is the userform in this case.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you so much! I tried almost three days figuring out how to solve this problem and wasn't able to find out how to properly interact with ListBoxes. Is there, by any chance, a website or book you recommend?

Comment: No problem. Most of the stuff I know comes from this website haha.

Comment: Hi @Alex de Jong , would it be possible to create ListBoxes dynamically directly on the worksheet? If so, how can i do that? Currently I am generating ListBoxes on my Worksheet like this but, again, I am sturggeling to address the Listboxes directly.
`Set LstBx = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ListBox.1", Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=692.25, Top:=180.75, Width:=96.75, Height _
        :=55.5).Select`

Comment: I tried something like this: `OS.Controls("Listbox" & i).AddItem cell.Value` and `OS.Forms("Listbox" & i).AddItem cell.Value` but it's not working unfortunately

Comment: You can take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56721002/how-do-i-inspect-the-name-of-each-combobox-on-a-worksheet-fo-a-particular-name-u/56732300#56732300